# Reverse proxy not working

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have an application correctly working on locahost:8080 and I am setting up a reverse proxy as follows but on a remote browser, when using the proxy, i am getting local links as if apache is ignoring the reverse proxy. The definition of the proxy is as follows:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /marmotta/ http://localhost:8080/marmotta/
ProxyPassReverse /marmotta/ http://localhost:8080/marmotta/
```

Any idea why this is not working ?

Comment: Can you share your full configuration file?